# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray Retornando null do SQlite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, image

Estou criando uma aplicação que eu cadastro uma imagem buscada da galeria do celular, salvando-a no SQLITE, e buscando posteriormente para mostrar em um recycler view, todavia, debugando percebi que o objeto bitmap está ficando nulo.

obs1: a informação esta sendo salva como objeto BLOB do SQLITE,

obs2: estou manipulando a imagem como byte[]

segue alguns codigos

INSERÇÃO NO SQLITE:

```
pacote.img = imageViewToByte(imag_pacote);


public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}


pacoteRepositorio.inserir(pacote);

  public void inserir(Pacote pacote){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("nome", pacote.nome);
    contentValues.put("img", String.valueOf(pacote.img));

    conexao.insertOrThrow("PACOTE",null, contentValues);
}
```

↑↑↑↑ Teoricamente está funcionando corretamente !!!!

CODIGO DE BUSCA *AQUI QUE ACREDITO ESTAR O ERRO

public List buscaPacotesPendentes() throws ParseException {
List pacotes = new ArrayList();

```
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("  SELECT * ");
    sql.append("  FROM PACOTE");
    sql.append("  WHERE pendente = 1");

    Cursor resultado = conexao.rawQuery(sql.toString(), null);

    if(resultado.getCount() > 0){
        resultado.moveToFirst();

        do{
            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Pacote pac  = new Pacote();
            pac.id       = resultado.getInt(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id"));
            pac.nome       = resultado.getString(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nome"));
            pac.img    = resultado.getBlob(resultado.getColumnIndexOrThrow("img"));

            pacotes.add(pac);

        }while(resultado.moveToNext());
    }
    return pacotes;
}

 byte[] imagen = pacote.img;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagen,0, imagen.length); //<< RETORNANDO NULL
        holder.img_pacote.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

[Aqui mostra que o BYTE[] está chegando normalmente, todavia quando coloco no Bitmap FICA null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U62xF.png)

obs3: vi que o objeto (byte[]imagen) está recebendo um array normalmente, com 11 posições

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO !!

O problema estava na hora de jogar o byte[] no banco de dados, ele tinha cerca de 215.000 posições mas quando eu tentei inserir foi só 11 pois parsiei para STRING

```
contentValues.put("img", String.valueOf(pacote.img));
```

o correto é

```
contentValues.put("img", pacote.img);
```